# Github doesn't display new travis builds near the commits

Tags: github, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I'm working on a simple app and got a problem with travis builds. I created a branch and a new pull-request with one commit and my build was failed as expected. When I fixed issues, I tried to push more commits and found that travis doesn't react on it. Then I push more commits with the same results - no travis reaction.
I checked my app on travis-ci.org and found that travis successfully created build on each commit. But github shows me only first failed build (see image below). Here is my `.travis.yml` file:

```
sudo: required
language: node_js
node_js:
- '13'
env:
  global:
  - PG_SQL_USER=hsxyxlxq
  - PG_SQL_HOST=balarama.db.elephantsql.com
  - PG_SQL_DB=hsxyxlxq
  - PG_SQL_TEST_USER=gskibphv
  - PG_SQL_TEST_HOST=drona.db.elephantsql.com
  - PG_SQL_TEST_DB=gskibphv
  - secure: #####
  - secure: #####
before_script:
- npm install
script:
- npm run migrate:test
- npm run test
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  app: richi-sh
  api_key:
    secure: #####
  on:
    repo: lutaev/richi
```

[image: no builds]

I'm new in CI, what should I do in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time asking on github and travis-ci forums I found that it is a travis-ci issue. To solve it I ended up doing a “hard reset”: revocking all authorizations from GitHub to Travis, then adding them again: GitHub > Settings > Applications > Authorized OAuth Apps revoke Travis CI for Open Source. Then I visited my Travis dashboard, log out, login again with GitHub and reauthorized. I also had to create an additional commit to make a build with successful status.